# Vim scan line for next character repeatedly with ; not working

Tags: vim

I am able to scan line for next character with <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>{char}</kbd> and repeat it with <kbd>;</kbd> or reverse with <kbd>,</kbd>.

But when I use <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>{char}</kbd> it does not work as <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>{char}</kbd>. It finds the first one but not able to repeat it with <kbd>;</kbd>.

Why is this?

---

### Update

#### My `.vimrc`

```
execute pathogen#infect()

syntax on
"filetype plugin indent on

set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2

colorscheme darkblue

set cursorline
hi Comment ctermfg=103
hi CursorLine term=none cterm=none ctermbg=17 guibg=236

set hlsearch
set number
set nowrap
set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
set cmdheight=1
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%<%F\ %m%r%h%w%{'['.(&fenc!=''?&fenc:&enc).']['.&ff.']'}%=%l,\ [TYPE=%Y]\ [ASCII=\%03.3b]\ [HEX=\%02.2B]\ %c%V%8P

nmap <C-l> <C-l>:nohlsearch<CR>

" http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/#installation
" ctrlp
set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with the results of `:verbose map ;` and `:verbose map t`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The behavior of ; to repeat the last t command bothers me. Can you help me make it better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523602/the-behavior-of-to-repeat-the-last-t-command-bothers-me-can-you-help-me-make)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make this work you need at least vim-7.3.235 and make sure you do not have `;` flag in `cpoptions` setting. Commit comment for vim-7.3.235:

```
updated for version 7.3.235
Problem:    ";" gets stuck on a "t" command, it's not useful.
Solution:   Add the ';' flag in 'cpo'. (Christian Brabandt)
```

.

---

By the way: you have issues in your vimrc:

1. The following:

   ```
   set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
   set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
   set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
   set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
   set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
   set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
   ```

   is complete equivalent to just

   ```
   set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
   ```

   and is useless since this `omnifunc` is supposed to be set in `ftplugin/php.vim` and indeed is set there (though with `setlocal` and not `set`). I suggest you just wipe all those lines.
2. `nnoremap` should be preferred over `nmap` unless you have very good reasons to write the opposite: [link](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have negative affection by some plugin. You can check this guess by running vim in command line without invoking any plugins and .vimrc like `vim -u NONE -N`. If you will be able to use semicolon for jumps reapiting after `t` command, then consequentially turn off your plugins one by one for finding problem one.

If it won't help please post your .vimrc.

Comment: Did you try run vim with "-u NONE" option?

Comment: @Myshov If you run it with `vim -u NONE` it will not work: `vim -u NONE` is running in compatible mode (unless you also provide `-N`) meaning that `;` flag in `cpoptions` mentioned in my answer is present. With this flag present `tc;` will not ever move to the next occurrence of `c`. Assuming you have at least vim-7.3.235 you can try it for yourself: run `vim -u NONE -s <(echo $'iabcdefghiabcdefghi\e0tc;')` and compare cursor position with `vim -u NONE -s <(echo $'iabcdefghiabcdefghi\e0tc;') -N`.

Comment: Oh, shame on me. Just forgot about default compatible mode, thank you for correction. I corretcted my answer according your clarifications.